# My src folder locked with only read permission in react-native project

Tags: git, react-native, file-permissions

I am developing the app in `react-native` and my code committed on git server but I am facing one strange issue.

Every time while I get to pull from git it will lock my src folder with **read-only** permission in my project and I cant able to modify that code and every time I need to provide **read-write** access from finder.

> Note: This issue is only for **MAC OS** while the same thing will not happen
>   on **Windows** machine.

To provide permission every time will be delaying my tasks.

Anyone facing the same issue of **read-only** permission in all **scr** & its subsidiary files.

Check attached screenshot for more detail.

> Failed to save 'DashboardScreen.js': A system error occurred (EACCES:
>   permission denied, open
>   '/Volumes/DATA/myapp/code//src/components/dashboard/DashboardScreen.js')

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I face this issue in Linux, I solved it by applying all permissions to the project folder and all its descendant.

```
sudo chmod -R 7777 <project_folder_name>
```

**OR**

In the file .git/config, I added a line that read: `sharedRepository = group`, like so:

```
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
        sharedRepository = group
```

Comment: you may please do the same using mac

Comment: as i said every time I give full permission to screen folder but when I pull from server through git it will change it to read only permission only.

Comment: you can use the second one.

Comment: Actually my Visual Code is updated and now I am not facing above issue Don't know its solve by your suggestion or VC tool done that any way thanks for your help. Now its working fine.